# Fail auto generate ID

Tags: vb.net

my program fails to auto count my id.Am i missing something. can someone pls help me and take a look

```
Private Sub getNextNumber()
        If Not app.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'open connection
            app.Open()
        End If

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select top 1 ID from ADMIN order by ID desc;", app)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        'fill data to datatable
        da.Fill(dt)
        app.Close()

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            txtID.Text = (Val(dt.Rows(0)(0)) + 1).ToString.PadLeft(10, "B")
        Else
            txtID.Text = "1".PadLeft(10, "B")
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Function getLastNumber() As Integer
    Dim app1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    app1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=MYX.accdb"
    If Not app1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        app1.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select top 1 ID from ADMIN order by ID desc;", app1)
    'desc = sort the data returned in descending order
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)
    app1.Close()

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return Val(dt.Rows(0)(0))
    End If
    Return 0
End Function
```

Have i coded it wrongly in this part?

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
          txtID.Text = (Val(dt.Rows(0)(0)) + 1).ToString.PadLeft(10, "B")
      Else
          txtID.Text = "1".PadLeft(10, "B")
      End If
```

Comment: _"fails to auto count my id"_ is not a good description of a problem. Please describe exactly what happens when you execute that code. Did you [step through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) the code? What's the value of `dt.Rows(0)(0)`?

Comment: Use debugger. Set a breakpoint and check the values of your objects. Any exception thrown?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Here is a bit of info from the docs on Val "The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number" If the ids you retrieve form the database start with a B you are not going to get anything.

Comment: @Mary after i use  Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. my insert data this command have error  If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then which mean i need change this code be another command. (Error 1 Option Strict On prohibits operands of type Object for operator '&'.)

Comment: That is correct. The Tag property can hold any type of data so its type is object. You need to cast the value back to the underlying type with .ToString of CInt() or whatever it was.

Comment: @Mary may i ask after i change tag (txtID.Tag)  to be other command but still face same issue. it is Textbox still can not auto count the id when user success key in the data. is i need setting some setting on my ms access database.

Comment: `txtID.Tag.ToString`

Answer (score 0):

`Using...End Using` blocks will close and dispose your database objects even if there is an error. You never have to check the state of your connection when you create it locally.

Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the sql statement and the connection directly to the constructor of the command. You don't need a `DataAdapter` or a `DataTable`.

`.ExecuteScalar` returns an object (the first row, first column of the result set) so we declare an Object variable outside the Using block so we can use it after the connection is closed. We can use `.ExecuteScalar` because you are only returning 1 row and only one column in that row.

Next, after the connection and command are duly closed and disposed, we check if `retVal` is `Nothing` and return 0 if is is.

If it passes the nothing test, change to a Char array. Use Linq to extract the numbers for the array. Finally it is joined into one string and converted to a number.

```
Private conString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=MYX.accdb"

Private Function getLastNumber() As Integer
    Dim retVal As Object
    Using app1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select top 1 ID from ADMIN order by ID desc;", app1)
            app1.Open()
            retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
    End Using
    If retVal Is Nothing Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Dim arrChar = retVal.ToString.ToCharArray()
    Dim result = (From c In arrChar
                  Where Char.IsNumber(c)
                  Select c).ToArray
    Dim num = CInt(String.Join("", result))
    Return num
End Function
```

Like wise your sub...

```
Private Sub GetNextID()
    Dim retVal As Object
    Using app As New OleDbConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select top 1 ID from ADMIN order by ID desc;", app)
            app.Open()
            retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using
    If retVal Is Nothing Then
        txtID.Text = "1".PadLeft(10, "B"c)
        Return
    End If
    Dim arrChar As Char() = retVal.ToString.ToCharArray
    Dim result = (From c In arrChar
                  Where Char.IsNumber(c)
                  Select c).ToArray
    Dim num = CInt(String.Join("", result))
    txtID.Text = (num + 1).ToString.PadLeft(10, "B"c)
End Sub
```

I hope this is single user or these methods will have big problems.